# Error: 400000 "Payload is either malformed or incomplete" When Publishing Workbook using API

Tags: postman, tableau-api

Im trying to publish a workbook to my Tableau Server using Tableau APIs. I am currently testing using Postman. There are 3 steps

1. Sign Into Tableau server and request Token for next step (Successful)
2. Create Project for the workbook and request project id for next step (Successful)
3. Publish workbook (Unsuccessful)

My Tableau Server version is **2021.4** and API version as suggested by Tableau is **3.14**.

This is my Request Boday

```
--boundary-string
Content-Disposition: name="request_payload"
Content-Type: text/xml
<tsRequest>
  <workbook name="Tableau_Test" showTabs="False" thumbnailsUserId="user-luid">
    <connections>
    <connection serverAddress="dbserver" serverPort="1234">
    <connectionCredentials name="uname" password="abc"
          embed="False" />
    </connection>
    </connections>
    <project id="9bad0c65-f5bb-4456-9f70-e89cc792a21d">
    </project>
  </workbook>
</tsRequest>
--boundary-string
Content-Disposition: name="Tableau_Test"; filename="Tableau_Test.twbx"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
content-of-workbook-
--boundary-string--
```

This is URI

```
https://horizonbi2.ocs-support.com/api/3.14/sites/ffbd84e1-0f55-403b-bb5b-ab007479e1e1/workbooks
```

Ive tried different API version and adding connections details in the request body. Nothing is working. Upgrading tableau server version is not possible as the requirement for wide company usage of tableau server version is specific to version 2021.4